# How to use normal ssh-agent on 18.04?

Tags: gnome, ssh, ssh-agent

I am using an 18.04 installation that has been upgraded from 17.10. When it was on 17.10, I pulled the GNOME SSH/GPG agent out, in favour of using the standard, command-line SSH agent. I wrote up the steps needed to do that [here](https://ticktockhouse.svbtle.com/my-obligatory-ubuntu-ssh-agent-post).

Now, after the upgrade, I find the the keys seem to have been imported into the GNOME 3 "Passwords and Keys" app, with the problems that that entails (e.g. when keys are deleted from here, they are deleted from my `~/.ssh` (!)/Keys show up with `ssh-add`, but aren't able to be deleted/added on the CLI). Worse still, I get a pop-up when I try to SSH into various machines for pasphrase-protected keys (though there seems to be some sort of timeout associated with this, and it seems to  cache it, at least for a while).

Any ideas about how to kill the GNOME app, and go back to using the normal `ssh-agent`, given the thigns that I've already put in place?

Comment: Does `seahorse` works for you?

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and eventually got it working. Not exactly sure what made the difference, but in addition to following the blog post, I ran `systemctl --user mask gpg-agent-ssh.socket` to make sure that it wasn't hijacking the openssh agent.

Comment: That makes sense because systemd would restart the ssh-agent used by gnome if you didn't disable the socket.